# Is there an Electron equivalent to Chrome's "Find in Page"?

Tags: electron

I want my Electron application to have the same behavior as Chrome, that when pressing F3, it should open the "Find in Page" searchbar. Is there an Electron equivalent to that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to implement that UI yourself, leveraging Electron's [`findInPage`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsfindinpagetext-options) and [`stopFindInPage`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsstopfindinpageaction) APIs and the [`found-in-page`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#event-found-in-page) event.

Comment: Thanks! One more little question, is it possible to exclude my custom search bar from the find results? Shadow DOM didn't work.

Comment: @Schnitzler don't know that there's a built in way. But how I set it up is the Find popup is a separate BrowserView/WebContents that sits on top of the page, so when I do a search, I only search the WebContents that's underneath, and so my Find popup gets implicitly excluded from the search.